# How to convert a complex Java Stream to loop?

Tags: java, loops, java-stream

I have a Stream expression that I want to convert to a simple loop in Java(either forEach or while). Below is the expression:

```
Stream.generate(taskFactory::createTask)
      .limit(limit)
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .map(taskMonitorFactory::startTask)
      .forEach(tasks::add);
```

I understand the concept that filter means if/else and map means for every entry, but I am not sure what to do about these generate and limit functions. I am really new to streams. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

`generate` is for stream creation and the `limit` tells how much elements should be retrieved - you can use some `for` loop instead

```
for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    Task task = taskFactory.createTask(); // assuming return type is some 'Task' class
    if(task != null) {
        task = taskMonitorFactory.startTask(task);
        tasks.add(task);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this really helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your stream translates to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    Optional.ofNullable(taskFactory.createTask())
      .map(taskMonitorFactory::startTask)
      .ifPresent(tasks::add);
}
```

Or old school:

```
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    Task task = taskFactory.createTask();
    if (task == null) {
        continue;
    }
    tasks.add(taskMonitorFactory.startTask(task));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this really helps